Representation Theorem for Random Measures
In his book "Random Measures, Theory and Applications", author Olav Kallenberg states on page 22 the following representation theorem for (locally finite) measures:
Lemma 1.6 (atomic decomposition) For any localized Borel space $S$, there
exists a decomposition
\begin{equation}
 \mu = \alpha + \sum_{k \leq \kappa}\beta_k \delta_{\sigma_k}, \quad \mu \in \mathcal{M}_S
\end{equation}
with $\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_S^\ast, \kappa \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}_+,\beta_1,\beta_2,\dots > 0$, and distinct $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots \in S$. The representation is unique up to the order of terms, and we may choose $\alpha,\kappa$ and all $(\beta_k, \sigma_k)$ to be measurable functions of $\mu$.
Note: in this book, locally-finite is defined with respect to some "localizing ring" (for metric spaces, this could be the ring of all bounded sets) on which the measure is required to be finite. Further, $\mathcal{M}_S$ denotes the set of locally-finite measures on $S$ and $\mathcal{M}_S^\ast$ the subset of locally-finite diffuse measures.
When Kallenberg introduces random measures, he states on page 49 that any random measure has the said atomic decomposition almost surely, with the $\sigma_k$ being almost surely distinct random elements on $S$, $\alpha$ a diffuse random measure, and $\beta_k > 0, \kappa \in \overline{\mathbb{Z}}_+$ random variables.
Question: I don't quite understand why these almost surely requirements are needed. From my understanding, we can represent $\alpha, \kappa$ and all $(\beta_k, \sigma_k)$ as measurable functions of $\mu$, and thus, once $\mu$ is specified as a measurable function of some abstract probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ - this is the definition of a random measure - we obtain a specification of these as measurable functions on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. No almost-surely assumtion needed.
Please help me out with this!
